# Show alarm with increasing sound with custom view in iOS 8,9

Tags: ios, notifications, ios8, ios9

Device running on iOS 8, iOS 9 or iOS 10 is locked and in sleep mode:
- Show alarm with increasing sound with custom view.

Any feedback much appreciated.

Comment: You can't, all you have to achieve this is [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) if you want to support all the give iOS version. And you are restriected to 30 seconds max to play a sound.

Comment: Many thanks for reply. When repeating notification in 30 seconds with let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 30, repeats: true), I get  error:  time interval must be at least 60 if repeating. So means repeating also is not possible, since we had to take 60 sec

Comment: Also `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` is only available in iOS 10, thus can not be used on iOS 8/9 devices.

Comment: thank you, may there be any other approach, except notifications, that could help deliver very important alarm to user on iOS 8, 9, 10 f.e by a permission request from Apple?

Comment: Apple only allows you to use public API for your apps. So your only option is `UILocalNotification` for iOS 8-10.